# How to put variable into a label text?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I wrote a tkinter code, with a label. There was a variable in the label text.

```
lab = Label(root, text = 'randomstrings', x, 'randomstrings')
    lab.pack()
```

When I ran the code, it gave an error message here: , x,

It said: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Well, you write `text='randomstrings'`, so what parameter is `x` supposed to fill in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put all label pieces together before passing them to the `Label`:

```
Label(root, text = 'randomstrings' + str(x) + 'randomstrings', ...)
```

or:

```
Label(root, text = 'randomstrings{}randomstring'.format(x), ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using commas to stitch strings together only works in the `print` function. Everywhere else you need to do the string formatting yourself:

```
lab = Label(root, text = 'randomstrings {} randomstrings'.format(x))
lab.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your problem

Commas are used to separate `Label()`'s arguments, so `x` and `'randomstrings'` are interpreted as `Label()` arguments. This is not what you want.

### Solution

You need to concatenate your strings.

You can use the `+` operator to do so:

```
lab = Label(root, text = 'randomstrings ' + x + ' randomstrings')
lab.pack()
```

If `x` is not a string, you can convert it with [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), like this:

```
lab = Label(root, text = 'randomstrings ' + str(x) + ' randomstrings')
lab.pack()
```